# How to convert CSV file to .txt file in R

Tags: r, csv, file-io, text-files

Given a huge CSV file, I want to read just the first 2000 lines of it and save it as a `.txt` file.

```
data<-read.csv("myfile", header=T, sep=",", nrow=2000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux/MacOS you can use `head` to do this without having to read the file:

```
head -n 2001 source_file > target_file
```

This assumes that there is a header, therefore the first 2001 rows in the file are put in `target_file`. Under Windows you can get this working by installing `Cygwin` or `MinGW`.

For solving your problem in R, you already have the content in R. Just use `write.csv` to write the data to a file.